# How to make Pax logging to use the loggback config instead of the standard log4j properties like syntax

Tags: osgi, logback, apache-felix, apache-karaf, pax

I have some services in tomcat and trying to move to apache karaf.

I have a existing service which uses logback for logging configuration.

I tried to make same configuration in osgi, but could not achieve. Any please let me know what could be the problem?

```
  org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg
         org.ops4j.pax.logging.logback.config.file=${karaf.home}/etc/logback.xml
```

logback.xml is available at ${karaf.home}/etc/
--.

Apache Karaf version : 3.0 , 
pax logging 1.7.1 which is packaged with karaf from build.

After above configuration change, my karaf.log contents are :

```
   Jul 02, 2014 4:21:32 PM org.apache.karaf.main.lock.SimpleFileLock lock
   .....................................................................
   INFO: Lock acquired
   Jul 02, 2014 4:21:32 PM org.apache.karaf.main.Main$KarafLockCallback lockAquired
   INFO: Lock acquired. Setting startlevel to 100
```

Comment: Karaf only ships with the log4j implementation by default, not logback. Have you added org.ops4j.pax.logging.logback to Karaf?

Comment: I have the below bundles in karaf, these coming with default startup.properties with karaf.   mvn\:org.ops4j.pax.logging/pax-logging-api/1.7.1 = 8
mvn\:org.ops4j.pax.logging/pax-logging-service/1.7.1 = 8 . do we need to add explicitly? I think logback bundle has dependencies to many other bundles. Whre can i find the more information?   Thanks

Comment: I'll leave that to somebody else to answer, but at least we've found out why your logback.xml is being ignored. :-)

Comment: Could you please let me know why logback.xml is ignored? As you suggested i added logback to karaf, but still the same problem. Thanks

Comment: @SrikanthHugar can you add your answer here?  How do you resolved it? Any pointers or document?

Comment: http://www.gharki.com/2014/07/how-to-configure-pax-logging-to-use.html may help you

Answer (score 1):

The logback backend of Pax Logging is in a separate bundle `mvn:org.ops4j.pax.logging/pax-logging-logback/1.7.1` which is not part of Karaf.

So if you didn't install this bundle manually, then it's no surprise that your `logback.xml` gets ignored.