# Using logback with Karaf 3.0.5 running under ServiceMix

Tags: logback, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

I am trying to use logback with Karaf 3.0.5 running under ServiceMix. This is what I have done till now as mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32033539/unable-to-make-logback-work-with-karaf-3-0-4).

This is what I have done till now:-

1. Removed `pax-logging-service` by doing `uninstall <pax-logging-bundle-id>`
2. Removed `lib/bin/karaf-client.jar`
3. Inside `lib` placed the following jars:- `jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.13`, `jul-to-slfj-17.13.jar`, `logback-classic-1.0.13.jar`, `logback-core-1.0.13.jar` &
   `osgi-over-slf4j-1.7.13.jar`
4. From `/etc/startup.properties` - removed references to `pax-logging-service` and `pax-logging-api`
5. In `etc/config.properties` under `org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra`added the following packages:-

   `ch.qos.logback; version="1.0.13", \
   org.slf4j; version="1.7.13", \`
6. Created a `logback.xml` and and placed it inside `/etc`.
7. Commented out everything in `etc/org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg`
8. In `etc/system.properties` add `logback.configurationFile="etc/logback.xml"`

My `logback.xml` looks like below:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    </appender>
    <appender name="FILE"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>/var/log/workflow/WorkFlow.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Karaf info reports the following:-

```
karaf@root>info
Karaf
  Karaf version               3.0.5
  Karaf home                  /home/jabong/Downloads/software/dev/apache-servicemix-6.1.0
  Karaf base                  /home/jabong/Downloads/software/dev/apache-servicemix-6.1.0
  Karaf etc                   /home/jabong/Downloads/software/dev/apache-servicemix-6.1.0/etc
  OSGi Framework              org.apache.felix.framework - 4.2.1
```

But after making the above changes we are not seeing any log file under `/var/log/workflow` nor I am seeing the info logs.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, you could place your pax-logging-logback jar under the system directory of the karaf/servicemix and then you could replace your org.ops4j.pax.logging with below configuration.

```
# use logback config
org.ops4j.pax.logging.logback.config.file=${karaf.base}/config/logback.xml
# set default 'osgi' logging level
org.ops4j.pax.logging.DefaultServiceLog.level=WARN
```

And place your logback.xml under config folder.